# Projects appearing twice in working sets - eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been spending the past day trying to fix a corrupted eclipse workspace. I have it synched on dropbox and it's been working fine for a long time but recently there was a problem with some conflicting files in the .metadata folder and it messed up everything, my projects just stopped showing in my project explorer.

I ended up re-importing the projects into the workspace and they show fine in project view, but when I try to place them in working sets each project appears twice. If I delete one of the duplicates, the other one gets deleted as well. Anyone know how to resolve this issue? I'd rather not delete .metadata since that would erase all my settings and preferences.

Comment: Sorry for experiencing it the hard way, but syncing Eclipse workspaces via dropbox is a bad idea as the metadata _is_ machine specific. Please get used to version control instead.

Comment: It's served me fine for a year now. I just like being able work on some assignments on my desktop, go to class with my laptop and automatically have my stuff there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd start a fresh workspace. Use the [preference export/import](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/timpandexp.htm) capabilities to ensure you retain all your favourite settings between workspaces.

I have never managed to save a corrupted workspace. Sometimes you've got to just let them go, like a [rabid dog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Yeller_%281957_film%29).

Comment: Bummer. What things will I have to transfer as well? Preferences, working sets, plugins?

Comment: Plugins will remain - those have been installed into your Eclipse installation, not your workspace. Most preferences will move across with the standard import/export feature. I would suggest you parallel run for a short period to check you've not missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether or not they are the same files shown twice. If this is the case then the solution is simple - go to 'Project Explorer' window, expand downward arrow to get the menu, then 'Project Presentation' -> 'Hierarchical'.