# Eclipse showing maven modules twice in project explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven project with around 20 modules. I have imported this project as maven project in my Eclipse [Neon Release (4.6.0)]. But when I see project in Java EE perspective it is showing every module twice, first set under the main project folder and the next set at the same level of main project[which is actually same].

The main problem here is that it takes double the time when I want to search for anything using Ctrl+H in eclipse. It shows result from the modules inside main project as well as from the modules which are at same level of main project folder[Though it has only one copy in hard drive]. Also if I try to search for method references[Ctrl+Shift+G] by opening a file from first set it doesn't show any result.

I want to know if there is any setting in eclipse which can make my project modules appear only once in my workspace.

[Explorer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmDnS.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540141/pydev-cause-duplicated-show-of-project-in-eclipse-j2ee-perspecitve

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have added explorer image for your reference. First set of modules which are visible under MyProject are not helping me in anyway. I tried "Filters.." as you suggested, but that didn't help.